# How to use regular expressions to match numbers with some exceptions

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match numbers in groups of 5, from 1 to 5, with the following exceptions:

1. Numbers can't include zeros
2. Numbers can't be like 11111, 22222 and so on.
3. Numbers can't be like 12345 or 54321

Some examples of valid numbers:

```
14252, 45121, 43412, 51321 ...
```

So far I got an expression to group the numbers and do not allow zeros.

```
/[1-5]{5}/
```

But I'm having some trouble to handle the second and third exceptions. I tried unsuccessfully to use a negative lookahead to disallow a match if I have a pattern of repeated numbers.

```
?!11111|?!22222
```

I'm trying with this expression:

```
((?!11111)[1-5]{5}?)
```

How can I write regular expressions to not match certain patterns?

I will eventually change it to not match any other sequence of numbers.

Comment: Why use a regex for your subsequent requirements? `str[/\A[1-5]{5}\z/] && str.chars.uniq.count > 1 && str.chars.uniqu.count < 5`

Comment: @meagar Perhaps make that an answer with explanation?

Comment: @Schwern No. That's why I added it as a comment. If I wanted to write an answer, I would have written an answer.

Comment: Is your "number" a string containing five digits?

Comment: What does your input look like? Are you trying to extract the number inside a string like `"Number 23451 is valid"`? Or do you already have the candidate number extracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't have to cram everything into one regex. Regexes are already complicated, if you can do it in multiple regexes, that will often make things much simpler and allow for more flexible code. For example, you can customize the error message based on which condition failed. Usually you only need to fold multiple regexes together for performance reasons, and there are tools to do that automatically.

> *So far I got an expression to group the numbers and do not allow zeros.*
>
> `/[1-5]{5}/`

Careful, you have to [anchor](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) at both ends that else it will accept any string that contains a run of 5 of 1-5.

```
/\A[1-5]{5}\z/
```

> *Numbers can't be like 11111, 22222 and so on.*

Use a [capture](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) within the regex to accomplish this. Capture the first number, then see if there's four more. `()` to capture and `\1` to refer to what was captured.

```
/\A([1-5])\1{4}\z/'
```

> *Numbers can't be like 12345 or 54321*

```
/\A(?:12345|54321)\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does not use a regular expression. I understand we are to determine if: a) the string contains five characters; b) each character equals '1', '2', '3', '4' or '5'; c) the string contains at least two different characters; and d) the string is neither '12345' nor '54321'. We can do that as follows.

```
def is_ok?(str)
  str.size == 5                              &&  # five characters
  (str.chars - ['1','2','3','4','5']).empty? &&  # only the digits '1'-'5'
  str.squeeze.size > 1                       &&  # not all the same character
  str != '12345'                             &&  # not an increasing sequence  
  str != '54321'                                 # not a decreasing sequence
end

is_ok? '12543' #=> true
is_ok? '12043' #=> false
is_ok? '12643' #=> false
is_ok? '22222' #=> false
is_ok? '12345' #=> false
is_ok? '54321' #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^(?!([1-5])\1{4})(?!54321)(?!12345)[1-5]{5}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea using negative lookaheads, just the syntax was a little off. This works for me:

`\A(?!11111|22222|33333|44444|55555|12345|54321)[1-5]{5}\z`

Comment: Switched from -1 to +1. :) Borrow `([1-5])\1{4}` from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46162331/14660) and we have a winner!